# Java: Date parsing, why do I get an error

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, unparseable

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ");//2018-02-05T18:00:51.001+0000
    String text = dateFormat.format(date);

    Date test = dateFormat.parse(text);
```

The first three lines work fine. When I try to parse the string into a date again I get an error. How can I solve this?

The error looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-02-07T15:32:13.214+0100"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at TimeRange.parseDateFromIsoString(TimeRange.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Your code works fine here. What error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");//2018-02-05T18:00:51.001+0000
    String text = dateFormat.format(date);

    try {
        Date test = dateFormat.parse(text);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

worked for me. With "SSSZ" instead of "SZ" at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I should like to contribute the modern answer. Because I discourage the use of `SimpleDateFormat`, more about that later.

### java.time

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx");
    String text = dateTime.format(formatter);
    OffsetDateTime test = OffsetDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
```

This produces a string like `2018-02-07T17:51:21.087+0100`, pretty close to what I think you were after in the question, and parses it back nicely. With `SSS` in the format pattern string it always produces 3 decimals on the seconds and also requires exactly 3 decimals by parsing. You may use `S` or `SSSSSS` to get 1 or 6 decimals, for example. On my Java 9, `OffsetDateTime.now()` has a precision of 6 decimals (microseconds), so if I specify fewer, I lose precision in the formatting.

EDIT: For backward compatibility you cannot use the following, but for anyone reading along I should like to present a variant without an explicit formatter:

```
    String text = dateTime.toString();
    OffsetDateTime test = OffsetDateTime.parse(text);
```

The two differences in the produced string are:

1. It produces as many groups of 3 decimals as are necessary to render the precision. Usually 3 decimals on my Java 8 and 6 decimals on my Java 9, but occassionally it hits a round number of milliseconds and produces fewer decimals. It parses a string with everything from 0 through 9 decimals, so this doesn’t present a problem in parsing. And I always preserve the full presicion of the original `OffsetDateTime` object.
2. The offset from UTC is rendered with a colon, for example `+01:00`.

### What went wrong in your code?

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome, so even if you hadn’t had a problem with it at present, I would still recommend you drop it and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead, as I do above.

One difference between the old `SimpleDateFormat` and the modern `DateTimeFormatter` is that while `S` in the modern formatter means fraction of second, in `SimpleDateFormat` it means milliseconds, so any other number than three is meaningless. However, it accepts other numbers. When formatting, your formatter produced enough digits for the milliseconds, for example `89` if there were 21.089 seconds or `214` when you had 13.214 as in the question.The former is incorrect, the 21.089 seconds were rendered as `21.89`. I strongly believe that three-digit milliseconds caused your parsing to fail when you had only one `S`. On my Java 8 and 9 it works and also parses `21.89` as 21 seconds 89 milliseconds so the error evens out.

This behaviour agrees with the Java 9 documentation, which states: “For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.”

### Link

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation for Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: sadly I can't change the format of my date-string as I have to be backwards-compatible and this doesn't seem to work with it.
thanks though :) it definitly is nicer

Comment: In that case you should ignore my variant without explicit formatter. The formatter, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx")` (with 3 `SSS`) parses and formats your examples from the question, 2018-02-05T18:00:51.001+0000 and 2018-02-07T15:32:13.214+0100, nicely, so please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I Removed Z in the simple date format which relates to time zone Which gives Correct out Put Below is the snippet.

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");//2018-02-05T18:00:51.001+0000
String text = dateFormat.format(date);

try {
    Date test = dateFormat.parse(text);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: but the dates I get have a timezone