# How to parse 2018-06-19T05:50:31.000+0000 date string to Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I tried this way but it throws an exception.

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ");
Date result =  date.parse(time);
```

I am getting this exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-06-19T05:50:31.000+0000"

How can I parse this date in Java?

Comment: Related: [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. agreed, though I've answered per the OP's use of simple date format.

Comment: @mrblewog maybe also add an example how to do it with the "new" api so OP can learn and others who stumble here using the simpledate library.

Comment: The format pattern letters are case sensitive. You need lowercase `yyyy`, lowercase `dd` and uppercase `HH`.

Comment: In any case [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670652/5772882) shows how to do it with `java.time` (the 4 years old API; maybe still “new” compared to the approx. 25 years old `SimpleDateFormat`?).

Comment: For modern solution, see: [*Java 8 Date and Time: parse ISO 8601 string without colon in offset*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46487403/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to make the T literal with single quotes, also the zone is a Z.

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`

See the examples here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: thanks it worked for me :)

Comment: @user3659493 would you mind accepting this answer then? Thanks.

Comment: Correct Answer. But now outdated. This class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: Hopefully the OP realises this. I answered in the terms of the question.