# How to parse String date to other date for other timezone

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin, jodatime, android-jodatime

Given I have such String date

```
val date =  "2019-01-07T13:54:00+0000"
```

How to parse this date to other timezone e.g "Asia/Kolkata"?

I was trying:

```
val zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata")

val resultMillis = ISODateTimeFormat
    .dateTimeParser()
    .withZone(zone)
    .parseDateTime(date)
```

But it did not worked

Comment: Are you using Joda-Time? If so, please tag the question accordingly to attract the right experts.

Comment: Related: [Java: Date parsing, why do I get an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666263/java-date-parsing-why-do-i-get-an-error)

Answer (score 1):

It’s a two-step process: You parse into the offset or time zone that is in the string, then you convert to your desired time zone. I can write only Java code, I trust you to translate:

```
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
    String date = "2019-01-07T13:54:00+0000";
    DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()
            .parseDateTime(date)
            .withZone(zone);
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Output is:

> 2019-01-07T19:24:00.000+05:30

You were almost there. I have textually just swapped the calls to `withZone` and `parseDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head comes the `TimeZone` class:

```
val date =  "2019-01-07T13:54:00+0000"
val zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")
```

Which `Calendar` understands:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(zone)
```

Then a `SimpleDateFormat` should do:

```
val format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
val simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
```

Comment: But how to pass the date to the Calendar?

Comment: I believe the `SimpleDateFormat` I posted should work. Code not run but you got the idea.

Comment: It does not work - I am using this https://www.epochconverter.com to check